# SoC Multi Cores and Boot Loaders

Tags: integrated-circuit, embedded, bootloader, core, soc

I have discovered that a typical SoC or MCU (multi core) have a boot loader which loads the bootstrap core. Could anyone tell me **does each core require its own dedicated boot loader** ? **Is it possible to load an additional core by the boot strap core and not by a boot loader** ? Can the boot loader reside anywhere on the die other then in flash memory or in EEPROM or ROM ? Finally using a multi core MCU or SoC IC's as an example **how does the boot loader know where to locate the core**? Please in your answer be detail as possible. Any links or resources would be appreciated too.

Comment: It cannot "be detail as possible" given how generic your question is. Details will greatly depend on the precise processor/platform used.

Comment: Even with something as low-end (in the realm of multicore) as Cortex-M, it's possible to make a SoC/board where the cores use different ROMs. See [this whitepaper](https://community.arm.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/8585-102-1-15361/Multi-core%20microcontroller%20design%20with%20Cortex-M%20processors%20and%20CoreSight%20SoC.pdf) for details.

Comment: Hello Respawned Fluff. Thank you for the response. I could understand what you meant by It cannot" ? Perhaps using as an example as a Qualcomm Snapdragon 810 or earlier SoC, can a ROM bootloader power on and make active a secondary core such as core3 ? Lastly do the cores (code) run in SRAM ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the bootloader is only run once on the first active core after reset.  Once software is running on the first core, the software can initialize the other cores.  I believe it is only possible to bring up other cores via the software running on the first core.

The bootloader could be in a number of places depending on the configuration.  It could be in addressable ROM of some sort (ROM, NOR flash, or EEPROM) either on-die or off-die.  Or it could be loaded in to RAM by a small hardware or software loader from an onboard ROM or offboard SPI flash chip.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'locate the core'.  If you are referring to deciding which core will start executing first, this would be hard-wired into the chip as which core is the only active core after a reset.  The bootloader would then start executing on this core.  After the bootloader starts, subsequent code would decide which additional cores to start.  This may or may not actually be done in the bootloader, though.  The bootloader is generally the component that loads the operating system, then the operating system would initialize the hardware and start the other cores.